# Element not being located by Xpath

Tags: html, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to click on a button in a table row. The relevant HTML code is given below:

```
<div id="catalogItems" class="col-xs-12">
...
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        ...
        <tbody id="existingItemsList">
            <tr id="item_3" class="info item" item_name="vegetables" role="form" item_id="3">
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr id="item_4" class="info item" item_name="pizza" role="form" item_id="4">
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr id="item_5" class="info item" item_name="Pastries" role="form" item_id="5">
                <td>
                    <button onclick=".." class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="item_6" class="info item" item_name="Burger" role="form" item_id="6">
         ...
```

I want to access the the button in the row with `item_name="pastries"` to run a test on it with Robot. My Xpath is given below:

```
xpath=//div[@id='catalogItems']//tr[@item_name=Pastries]//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-info']
```

With this, however, the button in the first row (`item_name="vegetables"`) is being selected by the Robot FW. How should I change the xpath to access the `item_name="pastries"` row? Please help!

Comment: Can you post whole html snippet? I tried this one + your xpath and it worked well.

Comment: you just forgot the quotes around 'Pastries' ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because you have an issue here, please cover Pastries with '', so it looks like 'Pastries'

```
//tr[@item_name='Pastries']
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what was missing.! Silly of me

Comment: Just for reference though, I don't see how this error accounts for the observed symptoms. The effect of missing the quotes should be that the XPath expression selects nothing. (Mind you, I have no idea what the "Robot FW" is...)